# How to open system SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, sms

I'm trying to open the SMS db (for censor app) with this code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

but it raises exception:

> 11-02 18:18:50.889: E/AndroidRuntime(17226): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

I can open it from the ADB shell.
Is it possible to open this db for rw? Or maybe it's possible only if I have root permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't open someone else's database unless your code is running with superuser access.  [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) are offered by many applications to allow restricted access to their data from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions problem. I'd say the db is read-only.