# SQLiteDatabase open specific database with path

Tags: android

I want to open a database that contains all sms and mms messages. I want to do so cause I need to make a raw query so I need to get it to work.
I am trying to do so like this:

```
    try{
      SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.android.providers/telephony/databases/mmssms.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I get an error like this:

```
07-15 10:13:11.784: E/SQLiteLog(13014): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
07-15 10:13:11.784: E/SQLiteLog(13014): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.android.providers/telephony/databases/mmssms.db) - 
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.android.providers/telephony/databases/mmssms.db'.
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at ppm.messenger.androidppmmessenger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 10:13:12.084: E/SQLiteDatabase(13014):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 10:13:12.094: W/System.err(13014): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
07-15 10:13:12.094: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
07-15 10:13:12.104: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
07-15 10:13:12.116: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
07-15 10:13:12.124: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
07-15 10:13:12.134: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
07-15 10:13:12.134: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
07-15 10:13:12.147: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
07-15 10:13:12.147: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
07-15 10:13:12.154: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
07-15 10:13:12.166: W/System.err(13014):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
07-15 10:13:12.174: W/System.err(13014):    at ppm.messenger.androidppmmessenger.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
07-15 10:13:12.174: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-15 10:13:12.185: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-15 10:13:12.194: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-15 10:13:12.194: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-15 10:13:12.204: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-15 10:13:12.214: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-15 10:13:12.224: W/System.err(13014):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-15 10:13:12.234: W/System.err(13014):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 10:13:12.234: W/System.err(13014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-15 10:13:12.244: W/System.err(13014):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 10:13:12.244: W/System.err(13014):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 10:13:12.254: W/System.err(13014):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-15 10:13:12.284: W/System.err(13014):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-15 10:13:12.294: W/System.err(13014):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I want to know how to open this database correctly.

Answer (score 1):

your question is not new. looks like you need to get some information how the connection to your database-servers is working.

answer is already given [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996445/how-to-open-system-sqlitedatabase)

Comment: Thank you. Now I just know that I can't open the database like this. And I understand why.